# Can R produce on-the-fly graphs for website?

Tags: sql-server, r

I use a Flex/ColdFusion/MSSQl combo to take  input from users to generate charts for a website . Is this possible in R? I have used RODBC and sqlQuery as a way of producing static graphs but cannot seem to find a way of doing it dynamically. Over to you JU

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can, you can use fantastic Apache module that allows stateless execution of R scripts - [RApache](http://rapache.net/). You can define an R script and catch (unserialize) plot parameters (e.g. via JSON or URL encoded string), plot the graph, and load result(s) with AJAX. That's pretty much what I did in [my app](https://github.com/aL3xa/univar-plot).

If you're not satisfied with R graph capabilities (and I'm sure that's so not gonna happen), you can try out `googleVis` or `canvas` packages. The first one is "only" a library for GoogleVis API for R, and I'm sure you'll like the later if you're familiar with HTML5 canvas. Some lads found it useful.

So, the final answer is, **yes, you can!**. You only need to decide whether you're going to generate graphs on client or server-side. Of course, even if you decide to generate graphs on the client side, you must massage your data in R and return it in serialized form (JSON or XML encoded). I know that ExtJS 4 also has good interface for creating client-side graphs, but I haven't used it much (read: "at all").

Comment: Thanks for that. The RApache  work done at UCLA http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~jeroen/irttool.html is the sort of thing I am after - although I really need it to be able to run on Windows. Looks like there are some more developments down the line including some work by Hadley Wickham http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSXNfZESR5I

Comment: Hey, np! But I'm not sure if I follow... you want to set up RApache on IIS or you want RApache applications to run on IE, or something else? =) Take a look at this one if the first one is your goal: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/vm.html